# class in JavaScript Vs Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I read on this ECMAScript [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) that 'class' is part of JavaScript. On this page about [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook), I see the 'class' is available in Typescript too.

My question is, the right approach to develop JavaScript applications FOR FUTURE is to take advantage of (a) the Object Oriented features in JavaScript and the features that will be availablein EMACScript 7.0 or (b) use libraries like TypeScript

Comment: Please define the "right" term.

Comment: What I meant by 'right' is to use language features rather than a framework feature so I can avoid the framework dependency. With that I don't have to worry about upgrading the framework when a new feature comes out.

Comment: If that works for **you** - use it. If it does not - do not.

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. But it's not used yet. ES6 has defined classes, but I suspect that browsers will take their time to implement them. Whether you should use native JavaScript, or use a dialect of JavaScript such as TypeScript is really personal preference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is, the right approach to develop JavaScript applications FOR FUTURE is to take advantage of (a) the Object Oriented features in JavaScript and the features that will be availablein EMACScript 7.0 or (b) use libraries like TypeScript

Either is fine. Depends upon if you want *type safety*.

If not there is stuff like `babeljs`. https://babeljs.io/

If yes then use `typescript` http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Worth to mention that the current stable version of TS does not support most of ES2015 features. Apart of that +1

Comment: I assume from your answer that the type safety is not going to be supported in JavaScript in the future, so the using JavaScript Vs TypeScript is purely based on type safety.

Comment: It might be supported in ES7+. But there is no concrete work on that.